# Nombre al crear nuevo proyecto en Android Studio y atributos XML uno debajo de otro

Tags: android, android-studio

A las buenas, a ver tengo una duda que yo supongo que con fáciles pero no consigo verlo. En primer lugar, he visto que hay gente que cuando comienza un proyecto con Android Studio, les aparece un comentario arriba que sale el nombre de la persona que lo crea y la fecha, o algo parecido, ¿como puedo poner esto?

Por otro lado en los archivos XML, antes cuando creaba una etiqueta nueva me aparecían los atributos unos debajo de otros, ahora me aparecen uno al lado del otro, que a mi parecer está desordenado

Antes aparecia algo así:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background_splashscreen"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Y ahora cuando creo una etiqueta me aparece así:

```
    <ImageView android:layout_width="" android:layout_height="" android:layout_above="" android:layout_centerHorizontal=""/>
```

Todo seguido, en una sola linea. ¿De qué forma puedo poner esto como estaba antes? Muchas gracias.

Comment: La segunda pregunta nose a que te refieres, respecto a la primera va ligado a si tienes el proyecto con git y con tus datos añadidos

Comment: Lo tengo con Git y con mis datos añadidos, pero no me aparece ese comentario en el proyecto... edito a ver si se entiende la segunda pregunta mejor.

Comment: [Formato XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53196252/android-studio-3-2-1-xml-bad-indent-format)

Comment: Genial lo del XML, a ver si me podéis decir lo del nombre :)

Comment: Simplemente da formato a tu xml Ctrl+alt+L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para editar su plantilla de encabezado de archivo, haga lo siguiente:

1) Abrir el diálogo de preferencias de Android Studio.

2) En el cuadro de búsqueda, escriba "Plantillas de archivo y código".

3) Seleccione la opción de menú izquierda "Plantillas de archivo y código".

4) Desde la sección de navegación tabular central, seleccione Incluye.

5) Seleccione el elemento del encabezado de archivo que se aplica a los archivos de Java.

6) Encontrará una sección de editor que le permitirá editarla para el patrón requerido. Use la sección de descripción a continuación para comprender los diferentes parámetros que se pueden usar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

**Mediante la secuencia de teclas**:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

**puedes dar formato a tu código u xmls en tu proyecto.**

también lo puedes realizar desde el menú:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Para poder aplicar el formato es importante que tengas aplicada la configuración para poder realizar cambios en el formato de los XML**, ve a:

`File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `Code Style` > `XML` , verifica que este seleccionado:

```
Use custom formatting settings for Android XML files
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, pero no se cambiaba así. Con el comentario que me habían puesto mas arriba se soluciona, si daba formato sin cambiar eso, daba igual las veces que hiciera el reformat code

Comment: @Isaac me parece que no tenías "Wrap always" si no tenías selecionado "Use custom formatting settings for Android XML files". Si es así solo no aplicaría el formato para los archivos XML, actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: ¿Y ahora a quien le doy la respuesta si me habéis respondido tu una y el otro usuario otra? jajajajaja

Comment: @Isaac me parece que ambas respuestas son diferentes, la otra se refiere al editar las plantillas,pero eso no estoy seguro si funciona en este caso.

Comment: pero puedo marcar dos respuestas?

Comment: No, el sistema no lo permite, solo la que consideres adecuada.

Comment: He optado por el que menos reputación tiene, para que le suba :)

Comment: OK, si, solo que el usuario YemisiSCG que realizo el comentario no es el que realizo la respesta :) jaja, y esa respuesta que se agrego no estoy seguro resuelva el cambio de formato  solo edita las platillas.